# How to set such section background or how to cut it from PSD

Tags: html, css, templates, frontend, photoshop

I'm trying to code such template : https://dribbble.com/shots/2622341-Maker-Free-PSD-Landing

I have problems with projects section background. I would be grateful for any suggestion whether I can achieve it by only CSS or how can I export it from psd with that effect.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi cinek, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide code that you have tried out so we can debug it. This is a too broad question n will be flagged.